# Can I md5(sha1(password))?

Tags: php, md5, sha1

I'm currently coding my own CMS and I'm at the state of password...

I want to know if I can `md5` a password then `sha1` it after?

Like:

```
$password = md5(sha1(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passw'])));
```

Comment: You can compute the md5 of the sha1 of any sequence of bytes. Why do you ask?

Comment: I'm asking 'cause I don't want to crash my CMS! So I can?

Comment: Just a note, you shouldn't escape passwords, when they're hashed with alphanumeric hashes like md5, sha1, etc, they can't contain any harmful characters - and it may alter the password the user expects.

Comment: Are you aware that in your example, you'll get an `MD5` string, not a `SHA1` one? You'll need to swap `md5` and `sha1` around if you want to '`sha1` it after'.

Comment: @Dan although you latter statement is true, the former is not. First, it depends on the output format and a hash result *may* require escaping. Second, it is always a good habit *not to think* if you have to escape your string or not. It should be unconditional. Just to me sure.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel - By former statement you mean, the alphanumeric hashes bit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `md5` any data you'd like, even if it was hashed before.

It will, however, only increase the risk of collisions because you're now working on a smaller dataset.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the best security for my password without 1000 of lines!

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux you'll get no added security from running a SHA1 password through the weaker MD5 algorithm.

Comment: The best security comes from the strength of the hash function itself.  What you can do however quite easily is use [salts](http://highedwebtech.com/2008/04/25/season-your-passwords-with-some-salt/) to improve the strength of commonly used (i.e. commonly precomputed) hash function values;

Comment: I doubt that a dataset would be really smaller

Comment: @YourCommonSense Please clarify if the dataset gets reduced on rehashing or not, as the answer makes a bold claim that risk of collisions will now be increased?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can.
No it doesn't make sense.

The security of chained hash functions is allways equal to or less than the security of the weakest algorithm.

i.e. md5(sha1($something)) is not more secure, than sha1($something): If you manage to break the sha1, you get the md5 for free, as shat($something) and sha1($faked_something) have the same value, and thus md5ing them will not change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add a salt in there too, this makes it much harder to use rainbow tables against your customer's/user's passwords.

Something like:

$hashedPassword = sha1(md5($password) . $salt . sha1($salt . $password));

Where salt can be a nice long random string itself, either constant across your application or a salt per contact which is stored with the user too.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously can. I don't see why you couldn't.

If you want better security you should consider something like [**phpass**](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but there's no real benefit to it. If you're running your passwords through `md5()`, you'll get a bit more security from adding a cryptographic salt.

[What is SALT and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584620/what-is-salt-and-how-do-i-use-it) has more info on that.

The other bit of advice you may hear a lot is to not use `MD5`. `SHA1` is comparatively stronger, and you only need to change your password field in your database to accept a 40 character string.